# $\ker (T \otimes id_{Z})=\ker(T)\otimes Z$

Tags: vector-spaces, modules, tensor-products, abelian-groups

Does $x\otimes y=0 \implies x=0$ or $y=0$? I don't think so, since its equivalent to $B(x,y)=0$ for some bi-linear form.

But my teacher said: $\ker (T \otimes id_{Z})=\ker(T)\otimes Z$ where $id_{Z}:Z\to Z$ is the identity map.

But $\ker(T \otimes id_{Z})=\{v\otimes z: Tv \otimes z=0\} \subset \ker(T) \otimes Z$, but are they really equal ? In fact $im(T) \otimes \{0\}$ is in the kernel.

Comment: What are $T$ and $Z$ here? The first implication is false for general modules; for example, $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes \mathbb{Z}_q = 0$ for distinct primes $p, q$.

Comment: $T:V\to W$ is a linear map where $V,W,Z$ are vector spaces over some field $F$ (may be infinite dimensional too)

Comment: Ah, OK, it's fine for vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This argument should be polished up a bit, but here goes: Changing the notation a bit, let $X, Y, Z$ be vector spaces over some field $k$, and let $T:X \to Z$. Set $T' = T\otimes \text{id}_Y : X\otimes Y \to Z$. Let $v$ be an arbitrary element of $\ker T'$, and write $v = x_1\otimes y_1 + \cdots + x_n\otimes y_n$ with $x_i\in X$, $y_i\in Y$. Assume without loss of generality that the $y_i$ are linearly independent. The vector $T'(v) = T(x_1) \otimes y_1 + \cdots + T(x_n)\otimes y_n = 0$.

Suppose some $Tx_i\not = 0$. Choose a map $\lambda:X \to k$ such that $\lambda(Tx_i)\not =0 $. Then the map
$$L = \lambda\otimes \text{id}_Y : X\otimes Y \to k\otimes Y = Y$$
has $L(T'v) \not = 0$, contradicing the assumption that $v'\in \ker T$. It follows that all $T(x_i) = 0$, and thus $(\ker T)\otimes Y\supset \ker T'$. The opposite inclusion is trivial.

Comment: Okay but in general does $x \otimes y=0 \implies x=0$ or $y=0$ ? where $x,y$ are vecotrs

Comment: Yes. If $x$ and $y$ are nonzero, take the corresponding elements $\lambda_x, \lambda_y$ in the duals $X^*$ and $Y^*$. Then $(\lambda_x\otimes \lambda_y)(x\otimes y) \not = 0$, so $x\otimes y\not = 0$.

Comment: hmm why $(\lambda_{x} \otimes \lambda_{y})(x \otimes y) \neq 0$ ?

Comment: Well if $T:X\to Z$ the  shouldn't $T':X \otimes Y \to Z \otimes Y$ ?

Comment: Slightly different setup: For $\lambda_x : X \to k$ and $\lambda_y : Y \to k$, the map $\lambda_x\otimes \lambda_y : X\otimes Y \to k\otimes k = k$. (The tensor product $X\otimes Y \to V\otimes W$ of maps $X\to V, Y \to W$ is well-defined even if $V\not = W$.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a more general reason as to why this is true. Every $F$-vector space is free. Thus, $Z$ is flat. In particular, tensoring with $Z$ preserves kernels.

Comment: Sure, but I'd assume from the question that the poster isn't familiar with flatness.

Comment: Of course, NOT :D

Comment: @anomaly I guessed as much. Still, the answer can serve as a motivation for flat modules. Also, it might be useful for others who read this question.

Comment: @AymanHourieh That is true. :)